# Refactoring a hash to Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method that return a Hash and then I write the entries of hash in xml file. Iwant to convert this Hash to an object to store the entry and then write it to xml file...
My current code is like this

```
def entry(city)
          {
            :loc => ActionController::Integration::Session.new.url_for(:controller => 'cities', :action => 'show', :city_name => city.name, :host => @country_host.value),
            :changefreq => 0.8,
            :priority => 'monthly',
            :lastmod => city.updated_at
          }
end
```

The write_entry method is inside my writer class that writes this entry to xml file

```
   def write_entry(entry)
      url = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( "url" , @xml_document )
      %w{loc changefreq priority lastmod}.each do |node|
        url <<  Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( node, @xml_document ).tap do |n| 
          n.content = entry[ node.to_sym ] 
        end  
      end
      url.to_xml
    end
```

Thanks

Comment: A Hash *is* an object. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to do have another class that maps the entries from city class and write it to xml file.
Something like that in my entry method Map.new(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be way off here, but it seems like what you're trying to do is something like this:

First, figure out what makes sense as a class name for your new object. I'm going with Entry, because that's the name of your method:

```
class Entry
end
```

Then take all the "properties" of your hash and make them reader methods on the object:

```
class Entry
  attr_reader :loc, :action, :changefreq, :priority, :lastmod
end
```

Next you need to decide how this object will be initialized. It seems like you will need both the city and @country_host for this:

```
class Entry
  attr_reader :loc, :action, :changefreq, :priority, :last mod

  def initialize(city, country_host_value)
    @loc = ActionController::Integration::Session.new.url_for(:controller => 'cities', :action => 'show', :city_name => city.name, :host => country_host_value)
    @changefreq = 0.8 # might actually want to just make this a constant
    @priority = 'monthly' # another constant here???
    @lastmod = city.updated_at
  end
end
```

Finally add your XML builder method to the class:

```
class Entry
  attr_reader :loc, :action, :changefreq, :priority, :last mod

  def initialize(city, country_host_value)
    @loc = ActionController::Integration::Session.new.url_for(:controller => 'cities', :action => 'show', :city_name => city.name, :host => country_host_value)
    @changefreq = 0.8 # might actually want to just make this a constant
    @priority = 'monthly' # another constant here???
    @lastmod = city.updated_at
  end

  def write_entry_to_xml(xml_document)
    url = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( "url" , xml_document )
    %w{loc changefreq priority lastmod}.each do |node|
      url <<  Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( node, xml_document ).tap do |n| 
        n.content = send(node)
      end  
    end
    url.to_xml
  end
end
```

Now that your hash has been refactored, you can update your other class(es) to use the new object:

```
class WhateverClassThisIs
  def entry(city)
    Entry.new(city, @country_host.value)
  end
end
```

It's not clear how the XML writer method is being called, but you would need to update that as well to use the new write_entry_to_xml method, passing in the xml document as an argument.

Comment: No prob! If you're interested in reading more on this subject, I recommend "Refactoring Ruby" by Jay Fields.